# WPF ControlTemplate Height

Tags: wpf, errortemplate

I have the following style for validating input in my controls:

```
<Style x:Key="MyErrorTemplate" TargetType="Control">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate x:Name="ControlErrorTemplate">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="Auto">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="Holder"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Label Foreground="Red" Content="{Binding ElementName=Holder, 
                            Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

If an error happens, the error message in the label appears under the control (e.g. textbox) and overlaps the control below. I made StackPanel's  Height="Auto", but it didn't help. Each control is in a Grid cell, and the Grid's row Height is also Auto. 
Could you please tell me what I am missing? I want the error message to push what is below down.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Validation.ErrorTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate.aspx) shows error feedback on an adorner layer. This means all controls in this template will not be considered when the layout system is measuring and arranging the controls on the adorned element layer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this mean nothing can be done to make it behave as I would like it to?

Comment: I think you have to move your Label to the adorned element layer (below your control) and trigger it's Visibility with [Validation.HasError Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.haserror.aspx) and a BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and thanks LPL, i did not know that about the adorner layer.

My solution was a margin "hack".  I just used the trigger:

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,28"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

To increase the bottom margin of the adorned textbox.  I set the margin large enough to make room for a single string textblock/label and then the content below was moved down